# What is std::views::all introduced for in C++20?

Tags: c++, standards, c++20, std, std-ranges

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4};
    v | std::views::drop(2); // ok
    std::views::all(v) | std::views::drop(2); // also ok
}
```

Successfully compiled with `g++11 -std=c++20`. But I cannot tell any difference between `v | std::views::drop(2)` and `std::views::all(v) | std::views::drop(2)`.

So, my question is:

**What is** [`std::views::all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view) **introduced for in C++20?**

Comment: For C++14/17 and C++20 that does not have `__cpp_lib_ranges` feature — like mine (/cry) — you can use Eric Niebler's Range-v3 `#include <range/v3/all.hpp>`, and use `ranges::views::all` and `range::views::take`.  I think in the example `std::views::all(v)` is just being explicit about the vector being used as-a `view`.  For a range-savvy code base I'd omit it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> But I cannot tell any difference between `v | std::views::drop(2)` and `std::views::all(v) | std::views::drop(2)`.

Indeed, there is no difference between the two - because `v | views::drop(2)` already means `views::all(v) | views::drop(2)`.

`views::all` is an implementation detail of Ranges to ensure that range adaptors always adapt *views* (not ranges). All that `views::all(v)` does is ensure that the result is a View, which is to say (from [[range.all]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.all)):

> Given a subexpression `E`, the expression `views​::​all(E)` is expression-equivalent to:
>
> - `decay-copy(E)` if the decayed type of `E` models `view`.
> - Otherwise, `ref_­view{E}` if that expression is well-formed.
> - Otherwise, `subrange{E}`.

In your case, `v` is a `vector<int>`, which does not model `view`. But it is an lvalue, so `ref_view{v}` would be well-formed, so that's what happens.

All the adaptors use `views::all` internally. For instance, `drop_view` has the following deduction guide:

```cpp
template <class R>
drop_view(R&&, range_difference_t<R>) -> drop_view<views::all_t<R>>;
```

So if you wrote `drop_view(v, 2)` (and you should never use `meow_view` directly, always use `views::meow`), that would itself invoke `views::all` for you.

Comment: So it's there to prevent you from using prvalue ranges that contain their elements in view compositions, unless you explicitly request it.

Comment: @Barry sorry I meant it as a follow-up to the other comment, but it is irrelevant and I deleted it. My bad!

Comment: With the introduction of C++23 `owning_view`, I think this answer can be updated. In addition, I think `views::all` should be more *specialized* in some cases, that is, when `E` is `string&`, `views::all(E)` should be `string_view`, and when `E` is `contiguous_range&`, `view::all(E)` should be `span`, because they are more convenient for users than `ref_view`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 `string&` and `string_view` give you different kinds of elements, so `views::all(E)` on a `string&` had really better not give you a `string_view`, that is totally wrong.

Comment: @Barry Oops, you are right, sometimes `view`s can be modified...

Comment: @康桓瑋 `owning_view` is listed by cppreference as existing since C++20. That said, it's not clear to me what _it_ exists for, much less how that relates to `views::all` :-) Is it intended as another implementation detail or ranges, or a quick way to make any range type into a move-only version of itself?

Comment: @underscore_d. see [*What is a view?*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html)

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thanks. I saw just before your reply that now `owning_view` is documented by cppreference as the last-ditch expression-equivalence for `views::all`, replacing `subrange`, so it exists to enable viewing rvalue ranges. I may ponder if I can find a use of `owning_view` as a general (not too evil?) way to make a copyable range type move-only!

Comment: Was P2415 a DR applied to C++20, or is it only for C++23 making cppreference wrong? My g++/libstdc++ does not have `owning_view`. **edit**: It seems [the former is true](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4902.html)

Comment: [Today I Learned](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2023/03/14/prefer-views-meow/#viewsmeow-is-the-algorithm) that `meow` above is a [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). In other words, it is a [placeholder](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/11ramwj/comment/jc94yxj/) (other common ones include `foo` and `bar`). In the specific above it means instead of `drop_view(v, 2)` use `views::drop(v, 2)`. Similarly for other adapters such as `take` instead of `take_view(v, 2)` use `views::take(v, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want your interface to return a range instead of the underlying container.  In the example below, `container_api` exposes member methods (i.e. of std::vector) that aren't part of a view (e.g. rbegin(), capacity(), max_size()).  `range_api` exposes `operator bool`, which isn't part of a vector.

Another important difference is that the return type of `range_api` is an object and not a reference.  This may prevent unintentional copies from users thinking they are getting a range when the actual interface is returning a reference to a container.

```
class Foo {
public:
     Foo() { ... }
     const auto& container_api() const { return m_vec; }
     auto range_api() const { return std::views::all(m_vec); }
private:
     std::vector<int> m_vec;
};

void some_fn(const Foo& foo)
{
   auto rng = foo.container_api();   // unwanted copy!
   ...
}
```